# Inserting object in HashMap

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, equals, hashcode

In HashMap when we enter a object, it calculate the hashCode for the key then go  to the bucket that it points. If the bucket already contains another object of the same key but the values are not same. Should it overload the equal() method and how? please help

Comment: What is your question ? rewrite these libraries, make another ones ? you can read the source also ...

Comment: If the map alreay contains a value for that key, then the new value replaces the old one associated with that key. That's documented: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#put-K-V-

Comment: can u just explain how do we override hashCode() and equals() in HashMap?

Comment: You don't override  these methods in HashMap. You override these methods in your class, if you want it to be used as a key of a HashMap, and if two different instances can be equal.

Comment: so if two different keys gives the same hashCode then what will happen?

Comment: They will end up in the same bucket, and the HashMap will store both entries in a linked list. Note that this can happen even if the keys don't have the same hashCode: hashCode can return 2^32 values, but the map obviously doesn't have 2^32 buckets. So many hashCodes share the same bucket.

Comment: i guess that's where overriding equals() method comes into picture, to distinguish each entry in the same bucket. am i right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a value-pair matter.

As long as you put a *key*/*value* pair to a `Hashmap`, if the *key* is the same, the old entry will be overwritten with the new one.

The values will never get compared to each other, you put what you want in a `Hashmap`, the `Hashmap` isn't supposed to warn you when you are overwriting an entry.

> public V put(K key,
>       V value)
>
> Associates the specified value with the specified key in this map. If
>   the map previously contained a mapping for the key, the old value is replaced.

Comment: i was given a task of creating a collection of objects for employee class( ename, age, dept)  where i had to arrange the employee object according to their names and if they have identical names then order them by age and age is same then order them by dept. so how do i approach?

Comment: Use a unique identifier for the key, the name isn't a valid identifier in your case.

Comment: @user5533204 it looks like you were asked to sort a list of emplyees, not to use a HashMap. Google for "sort list of objects in Java".